# laravel collection methods with custom attributes

Tags: laravel, collections, filter, eloquent, attributes

is there a way to use for eloquent collection methods like **map,filter** on custom attributes ?

```
    public function getDoneAttribute(){
        true;
    }    

    $uncomplete_todos = $todos->filter(function($key,$value){
        return $value->done;
    });
```

this error shows up 
        Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return` something from the accessor:

```
public function getDoneAttribute(){
    return true;
}
```

Also, you're trying to use a key as an object. Do this instead:

```
$uncomplete_todos = $todos->filter(function($value, $key) {
    return $value->done;
});
```

Comment: ou, stupid mistake I would not find out. Thanks. It's working